# Reading input char by char using realloc in C

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I would like to read input char by char and save it as a word into char* array. I don't know how long the input will be,  so i want to alloc the memmory dynamicaly. The program ends,when the char is whitespace. How can i do this using realloc?
There is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char *word=malloc(1*sizeof(char));
    char c;
    int numOfChars=0;
    c=getchar();
    word[0]=c;
    numOfChars++;
    while((c=getchar())!=' '){
        numOfChars++;
        realloc(word,numOfChars);
        word[numofChars-1]=c;
    }
    printf("%s", word);

    return 0;
}
```

Example input:`Word`
Example output:`Word`

Comment: Don't forget that strings must be NUL terminated (have a '\0' at the end otherwise your `printf` will read out of bounds. (The NUL itself needs a byte to be stored, I'll leave it up to you to figure out what you need to do with your array size to handle that.) Btw, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`.

Comment: I would not recommend to use realloc to allocate one more position to a string. This will be inefficient.  Instead try to double the size when necessary and shrink the allocate space to the minimum at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program can look the following way. Take into account that the input is buffered and filled until a new line character is entered that is also a white space character. And the result word must be zero terminated if you are going to use format specifier `%s` to output it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    int c;
    size_t n;
    char *word;
    char *tmp;

    n = 0;
    word = malloc( n + 1 );
    word[n++] = '\0';

    printf( "Enter a word: " );

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && !isspace( c ) && ( tmp = realloc( word, n + 1 ) ) != NULL )
    {
        word = tmp;
        word[n-1] = c;
        word[n++] = '\0';
    }

    printf( "You've entered \"%s\"\n", word );

    free( word );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a word: Hello
You've entered "Hello"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112597/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow-reading-input-char-by-char-using-reallo).

Answer (score 2):

In order to explain what I had in mind, i quickly set up this little programm to explain how to use an exponential growth :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 100
#define GROW_FACTOR 1.5

struct string_buffer {
  size_t capacity;
  size_t length;
  char *buffer;
};

typedef struct string_buffer string_buffer_t;

string_buffer_t *sb_init(void);
static void sb_grow(string_buffer_t *sb);
void sb_shrink(string_buffer_t *sb);
char *sb_release(string_buffer_t *sb);

void sb_append_char(string_buffer_t *sb, char c);
char *sb_peek_string(string_buffer_t *sb);

int main(void)
{
  string_buffer_t *sb=sb_init();
  int c;

  while ( (c=getchar())!=' ' && c!='\n' && c!=EOF )
    sb_append_char(sb, c);

  char *string=sb_release(sb);
  printf("string : \"%s\"\nlength : %zu\n", string, strlen(string));
  free(string);
  return 0;
}

string_buffer_t *sb_init(void)
{
  string_buffer_t *new=malloc(sizeof *new);
  if (new==NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  new->capacity=INITIAL_CAPACITY;
  new->length=1;
  new->buffer=malloc(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
  if (new->buffer==NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  new->buffer[0]=0;

  return new;
}

static void sb_grow(string_buffer_t *sb)
{
  char *new=realloc(sb->buffer, (size_t) (GROW_FACTOR*sb->capacity));
  if (new==NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  sb->capacity=(size_t) (GROW_FACTOR*sb->capacity);
  sb->buffer=new;
}

void sb_shrink(string_buffer_t *sb)
{
  char *new=realloc(sb->buffer, sb->length);
  if (new==NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  sb->buffer=new;
}

char *sb_release(string_buffer_t *sb)
{
  sb_shrink(sb);
  char *string=sb->buffer;
  free(sb);
  return string;
}

void sb_append_char(string_buffer_t *sb, char c)
{
  if (sb->capacity==sb->length) sb_grow(sb);
  sb->buffer[sb->length-1]=c;
  sb->buffer[sb->length]=0;
  sb->length=sb->length+1;
}
```

Comment: Consider adding a bit of explanation to this one so that it will be useful to someone in the longer run :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  char *ptr;
  char *word=malloc(1*sizeof *word);
  char c;
  int numofChars=0;
  printf("Enter string terminated by a space :");
  c=getchar();
  word[0]=c;
  numofChars++;

  while((c=getchar())!=' '){
    numofChars++;
    ptr=realloc(word,numofChars*sizeof *ptr);
    if(ptr!=NULL)
    {
      word=ptr;
      word[numofChars-1]=c;
    }
  }
  /* You need to append a null character to make it a valid string */
  numofChars++;
  ptr=realloc(word,numofChars*sizeof *ptr);
  if(ptr!=NULL)
  {
    word=ptr;
    word[numofChars-1]='\0';
  }

  printf("Word : %s\n", word);

  free(word); // Freeing word/

  return 0;
}
```

Well, you may write a function  to replace

```
 numofChars++;
      ptr=realloc(word,numofChars*sizeof *ptr);
      if(ptr!=NULL)
      {
        word=ptr;
        word[numofChars-1]='\0';
      }
```

**Note:**
It is not suggested that you do

```
  word=realloc(word,numOfChars*sizeof(char));
```

because in case `realloc` fails, you have memory leak. So I used `ptr` here.

Comment: You can directly assign to word pointer variable, why creating a new variable and assigning it ?

Comment: None of you mention that the input is _not_ NUL terminated. `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1` so there's no need to specify it at all.

Comment: @Jite : I already have a comment asking the op to append a null character.  It would just be a cut copy paste. Would you expect me to do that piece of code as well ? Read the answer carefully please ;)

Comment: Why `*sizeof(char));` (which is always `*1`)?   Suggest `ptr=realloc(word,numofChars);` or`clearly `ptr=realloc(word,numofChars*sizeof *ptr);`?

Comment: @chux : I would go with your second suggestion which I feel is more portable. Code Edited :)

Comment: @sjsam Your answer did **not** contain info about the NUL termination when I wrote the comment or else I wouldn't have written it.

Comment: @Jite : `Your answer did not contain info about the NUL termination` Not true. I did put a comment regarding this in the first version. You just didn't see it. See the edit history.

Comment: @sjsam No really, go check it for yourself, I just did, your first answer did **not** contain it.

Comment: @Jite: Well it was not the first version, sorry about that. ;) This was the [\[ second \]](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/183ec6cc-7ee2-4ff6-a2cb-fa021535542d/view-source) version of the answer  posted at May 20,11:06 and your down-vote certainly came after this at around the time you posted the first comment.. Now, no more arguments please, not interested in forensics ;)

Comment: @Jite : Can't blame you either, because you might have posted the comment with the first version of answer in your system where SO didn't notify you about an edit which has been made. Anyways at the end happy you happy me :-)